# Google PUBSUB API: When a binding is made through IAM (for a specific resource), will same member get all access of that role?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, messaging, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

The is in reference to code at official page, where we want to give access to a user for a specific PUBSUB subscription: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#setting_a_policy

In the above code:

- Role `roles/pubsub.editor` is binded to member `allUsers` for specific resource like 'pubsub.your-subscription-id'; the resource policy is updated in same terms.
- As far as I know 'roles/pubsub.editor' role has all access to PUBSUB subscriptions and policies.

Q)After executing the above code, can we conclude that `allUsers` get all accesses that  role `roles/pubsub.editor` has? Or is this binding only specific to this resource's policy? As I am a newbie here, please help if my understandings are wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

In Pub/Sub, access control can be configured at the project level and at the individual resource level.

If you assign IAM roles at the project level, that grants specific permissions to all Pub/Sub resources.

You can also grant access on a per-topic or per-subscription basis instead of granting access at the project level.

> Q)After executing the above code, can we conclude that allUsers get
> all accesses that role roles/pubsub.editor has? Or is this binding
> only specific to this resource's policy?

The documentation link that you provided is granting a role at the resource level for a **Subscription ID** and not for all subscriptions in the project. The member **all users** is being granted the role **roles/pubsub.viewer** and not the role **roles/pubsub.editor**. This role is granted only for the Subscription ID and not for other Subscription IDs.

Note: the documentation is slightly wrong. It is using the term **all users** where it is actually granting permission to **all authenticated users** in the google.com domain which means anyone who is logged into Gmail, Google Cloud, etc.

> As far as I know 'roles/pubsub.editor' role has all access to PUBSUB
> subscriptions and policies.

That is not correct. The role **roles/pubsub.editor** is a collection of permissions. Those permissions can then be attached to resources via IAM bindings. If the resource is a project, then yes, all Pub/Sub resources under the project. If the resource is a subscription ID, then the permissions are granted only for that subscription ID.

Comment: Thanks so much. It took me some time for me to learn that 'role' in GCP IAM should not be taken in literal meaning, but as collection of permissions. Your answer made it clear. :)